# pq: malformed array literal:

Tags: postgresql, go

I want to insert json array request like

```
{
    "name": "Sales Commission",
    "commission_type":"ZCo6QCHOBth7MD-8sohHQ",
    "time_period_from": "2022-05-13 12:00:00",
    "time_period_to": "2022-05-18 12:00:00",
    "service_id": [
        {
            "service_id": "1",
            "service_type": "1",
            "commission_type": "1",
            "commission_rate": "1.50"
        }
    ],
    "package_id": [
        {
            "package_id": "1",
            "package_type": "1",
            "commission_type": "1",
            "commission_rate": "1.50"
        }
    ],
    "product_id": [
        {
            "product_id": "1",
            "product_type": "1",
            "commission_type": "1",
            "commission_rate": "1.50"
        }
    ],
    "employee_id": [
        {
            "employee_id": "1",
            "commission_type": "1",
            "commission_rate": "10.50"
        }
    ],
    "status": "active"
}
```

I am using Golang with Postgres. I had made struct of the Model which is below:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Name           string      `json:"name"`
    CommissionType string      `json:"commission_type"`
    TimePeriodFrom string      `json:"time_period_from"`
    TimePeriodTo   string      `json:"time_period_to"`
    Services       []Services  `json:"service_id"`
    Packages       []Packages  `json:"package_id"`
    Products       []Products  `json:"product_id"`
    Employees      []Employees `json:"employee_id"`
    Status         string      `json:"status"`
}

type Services struct {
    ServiceID      string `json:"service_id"`
    ServiceType    string `json:"service_type"`
    CommissionType string `json:"commission_type"`
    CommissionRate string `json:"commission_rate"`
}
type Packages struct {
    PackageID      string `json:"package_id"`
    PackageType    string `json:"package_type"`
    CommissionType string `json:"commission_type"`
    CommissionRate string `json:"commission_rate"`
}
type Products struct {
    ProductID      string `json:"product_id"`
    ProductType    string `json:"product_type"`
    CommissionType string `json:"commission_type"`
    CommissionRate string `json:"commission_rate"`
}
type Employees struct {
    EmployeeID     string `json:"employee_id"`
    CommissionType string `json:"commission_type"`
    CommissionRate string `json:"commission_rate"`
}
```

Request which is being decoded

```
    var ReqMapData model.AutoGenerated
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&ReqMapData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
```

While performing data insertion I am facing this issue like "pq: malformed array literal: "[{"service_id":"1","service_type":"1","commission_type":"1","commission_rate":"1.50"}]"""

Code which inserts data

```
serJson, errJson := json.Marshal(reqMap.Services)
    if errJson != nil {
        util.CheckErrorLog(r, errJson)
        return false
    }

    pkgJson, errJson1 := json.Marshal(reqMap.Packages)
    if errJson1 != nil {
        util.CheckErrorLog(r, errJson1)
        return false
    }

    proJson, errJson2 := json.Marshal(reqMap.Products)
    if errJson2 != nil {
        util.CheckErrorLog(r, errJson2)
        return false
    }

    empJson, errJson3 := json.Marshal(reqMap.Employees)
    if errJson3 != nil {
        util.CheckErrorLog(r, errJson3)
        return false
    }

    Qry.WriteString("INSERT INTO commission_template(id, name, commission_type, time_period_from, time_period_to, service_id, package_id, product_id, employee_id, status) ")
    Qry.WriteString(" VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10);")
    err := ExecuteNonQuery(Qry.String(), nanoid, reqMap.Name, reqMap.CommissionType, reqMap.TimePeriodFrom, reqMap.TimePeriodTo, string(serJson), string(pkgJson), string(proJson), string(empJson), reqMap.Status)
    if err != nil {
        util.CheckErrorLog(r, err)
        return false
    }
```

```
// ExecuteNonQuery - Update, Insert Query
func ExecuteNonQuery(SQLQry string, params ...interface{}) error {
    _, err := VDB.Exec(SQLQry, params...)
    return err
}
```

Comment: Where is the Go code that attempts to insert that JSON into postgres?

Comment: I have updated the question please have a look @mkopriva

Comment: Ok. I have updated the question with insert query code. @mkopriva

Comment: In the postgres database, what is the type of the `commission_template.services_id` column? Is it `json`/`jsonb`? Or is it `json[]`/`jsonb[]` (an array of json)?

Comment: it's json[] @mkopriva

Comment: Then that's your problem. An array of JSON is not the same as a JSON array. Your `serJson`, `pkgJson`, `proJson`, etc. are all JSON. They are NOT *slices* nor *arrays* of JSON.

Comment: For inserting [{},{}] in postgres, what are the possible solutions for it?@mkopriva Appreciate your time for seeing this problem.

Comment: https://github.com/jackc/pgtype/blob/master/jsonb_array.go handles reading and writing postgres' `jsonb[]`, if I'm not mistaken it should work for `json[]` just as well. Example: `serJsonArray := new(pgtype.JSONBArray)`; `serJsonArray.Set([][]byte{serJson})` and then pass `serJsonArray` instead of `serJson` to `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: And just in case you haven't considered it, it would be much easier to just change the column type from `json[]` to `json`. Then you should be able to pass `serJson` to `ExecuteNonQuery` without any issues.

Comment: I changed it json from json[] and it worked. Thanks @mkopriva